# Intercepting Property Assignment with Attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to have an attribute placed on a property intercept an assignment call to that property?

An example of how I would use this is to make it so that a string property with this attribute on it would be set to `string.Empty` when the user assigns `null`.

I'm sure there are a lot of other possible uses for something like this, but at the moment this is what I'm looking for.

EDIT:

For example:

```
class A
{
    [NotNullableString]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

And `NotNullableStringAttribute` would check the input value for the `set` and if it is null replace it with `string.Empty` instead.

Comment: why not check for null in the setter and set it to string.Empty

Comment: or check for null in the Get()

Comment: @cheedep It would involve code duplication but more importantly it would be a bit less readable/obvious. Also, I would not be able to use the default `set` or `get` for the property.

Comment: Code duplication? it will probably save you one extra line of code. In my opinion it doesn't make it any more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this using C# Attributes you will need to use IL weaving.

The most popular library is PostSharp : http://ayende.com/blog/3640/first-steps-with-post-sharp The express version is free : http://www.postsharp.net/aspects

Comment: is postsharp free for use?

Comment: @David nope. Mentioned it in answer

Comment: I was looking for an addon-free way of doing this. If not then I can achieve this the long way.

Comment: @BASarat, thanks for redirecting me to the express/free version! Great job!

Comment: @BASarat Ah now I see. So PostSharp changes the IL. Nifty. Yes I could probably do what I'm looking for with that. If I don't get an answer for how to do it in pure C# I'll tick your answer. Thanks.

Comment: IL Weaving is the only way to do it if you want to intercept someone saying `SomeString = null`. Another solution is to use something like https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ Where you allow the initial assignment, Then check if the object is valid, If it is not valid you revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist that there be no post build step in your workflow AND you get to use attributes, then the answer is that it is currently not possible.